# SVG is not rendered if (obsolete?) AUX files are deleted beforehand

Tags: pdftex, luatex, compiling, svg, rendering

In my document I use a SVG file in the header (fancyhdr) and the same SVG is used independently on the title page. More or less like this:

```
...
\fancyhead[C]{
    \includesvg[]{images/my-svg-file}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north)}]
    \node[anchor=west]{some text before};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north)}]
    \node[anchor=north]{\includesvg[]{images/my-svg-file}}; % <-- will not be rendered
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north)}]
    \node[anchor=east]{some text after};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \newpage
  While the header is deactivated on the first page, this page has the correct header...
  \newpage
  ... so does this page.
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to compile this document using a batch script, so I can copy/rename the output PDF, delete all of those files that are generated during compilation (going to call them AUX files), and maybe do some other stuff.

This is my batch file, but I don't think it's relevant (since the same happens if I use the MikTeX editor for compilation):

```
lualatex --shell-escape --enable-write18 my_document.tex
DEL *.log
DEL *.out
DEL *.aux
DEL *.table
DEL *.lua
DEL *.dat
```

Now, the problem is, that the very first occurence of the SVG image (see the comment in the tex snippet) is not rendered, nor is the text "some text before" and "some text after".

But **only if the document is compiled without the AUX files existing in the .tex file's directory**.
I'd like to understand why that happens...
Shouldn't the compilation deliver the exact same results every time? How can files that exist from a previous compilation affect a subsequent compilation?!

That seems like a serious flaw to me because the document might have changed dramatically between two compilations.
In my opinion, the AUX files need to be considered obsolete after a compilation has finished, but I know little about LaTeX.

I know that I have some options:

- call the `luatex command twice` (tested this and it works, but it's ugly)
- copy the PDF away from the compilation directory, but that's not prefered

Instead I'd like to learn what causes the issue.

Comment: the main point of most aux file is to affect the next compilation. They contain for example info about labels, pagenumbers, bookmarks, and typically only the second or third compilation is correct (your log file probably contains a "rerun" message after the first compilation.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @UlrikeFischer. Is there an option to rerun the compilation automatically? If there isn't and if it is expected that a compilation has to be run "two **or** three" times to get the actual result, this mechanic is totally flawed IMHO! What if I want to run the compilation in a git pipeline (which I actually want to do at some point)? How would I know how often a certain document has to be compiled?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer a remarkable fact is that the same SVG import works at a later point in the document, i.e. in the same compilation. A fix I'd be satisfied with would be if I could import the SVG without actually rendering it anywhere in the document. So what is currently the first occurence of `\includesvg[]{}` becomes the second.

Comment: The svg is probably there, only not at the position where you expect it as you are using the `remember picture` key and this requires two compilations as the  position at shipout must be saved and then can be reused at the next compilation.   Why do you use tikzpictures instead of placing the svg directly?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use tikzpicture because I found I can place the SVG/text at arbitrary positions on the title page. I didn't know it would have implications. If that's what causes the problem I might look for an alternative... Thanks for spending your time!

Comment: If you're looking for an alternative, try the `textpos` package, that allows you to type arbitrary elements to any absolute coordinates on a page.

Comment: @SimSon You could compile the file using latexmk, this will automatically determine how many runs are necessary and if other tools need to be run. For a header image, I would not use `\includesvg`. Convert the svg to pdf and then directly use the pdf. This will save all the additional steps introduced by `\includesvg`.

Comment: @SimSon Instead of renaming the output, you could directly set the jobname during the compilation.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Well, package `svg` does exactly what you suggested. Once the svg file was converted to pdf and as long the svg file itself isn't changed, the converted pdf is included directly. But as `\includegraphics` is still used in every header, I would store the result in a box. Like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @mrpiggi The svg package will still need to check if the file has changed. This might be useful for included diagrams so they are always up-to-date, but a header image is most likely a static image. Converting it once manually seems much more effective. This also avoids the risk of compiling with shell-escape enabled.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz but wouldn't it be even more consistent to use a box within the header instead of calling `\includegraphics` each time?

regarding `--shell-escape` I totally agree with you. It is still on my todo list enabling package `svg` to be used in restricted mode once Inkscape was set to the trusted application by the user. Unfortunately, as with many other things, I lack the time for this.

Comment: @mrpiggi Yes, using a box there can't hurt. The point I tried to make is that while the svg package can be very useful, I don't this particular situation is a good use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated by @Ulrike you should not delete any generated aux file in order to get the final processed document after several runs. In fact, package `svg` uses the aux file itself to determine the Inkscape version used.

Nevertheless, using the same SVG file multiple times, I would highly recommend you to store this into a box once included and use this for your headers. Otherwise, the SVG file will be processed for each page without any benefit but an impact in performance, especially when used in a header for a large document.

So a very simple approach would look like this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\newbox\fancyheadbox
\savebox\fancyheadbox{\rule{100pt}{5pt}}
%\savebox\fancyheadbox{\includesvg[]{images/my-svg-file}}
\fancyhead[C]{\usebox\fancyheadbox}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north)}]
    \node[anchor=west]{some text before};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north)}]
    \node[anchor=north]{\usebox\fancyheadbox}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north)}]
    \node[anchor=east]{some text after};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \newpage
  While the header is deactivated on the first page, this page has the correct 
  header...
  \newpage
  ... so does this page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should normally not do "typesetting" in the preamble,  fonts are yet fully setup.  And if svg needs something from the aux the preamble is too early too.

Comment: You are right, answer edited.